# How to publish post to individual based on date

Tags: plugins, scheduled-posts

I am creating a website for pregnant women, upon registration I am asking for their  expected due date.  The experience I need is:

- When a user registers they enter their child's due date as one of the fields,
- their homepage then shows a post based on what week of their pregnancy they are in (eg - "You're now 18 weeks pregnant, your baby is the size of an artichoke")
- that post then disappears when a user logs in the next week, and the subsequent post for that week is displayed, (eg - "You're now 19 weeks pregnant...")

I've tried looking at Ultimate Member (https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) and the Private Content (https://ultimatemember.com/extensions/private-content/) plugin but that only creates private content for that individual.

I also came across this post: [Limit content by user registration date](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229475/limit-content-by-user-registration-date) (hoping to leverage the registration date) but as we have 40 weeks of content that code in the Answer is not suitable.

What's the best approach here?

Comment: Some themes have a 'featured post', and you can usually override the logic that chooses it either by a filter or by overriding a pluggable function. You could use something like that: dynamically choose the featured post based on the current user's due date.

Comment: How to select the right post? You could either just hard-code the list in your child theme, or at the expense of a database lookup you could put a day range or a day threshold on each post as a post meta property, and put all of these posts in a specific category or tag: then you can query the list of posts to get the mapping of range / threshold to post ID. It'd be worth checking how expensive that is and probably caching the result in a transient, either the mapping or a per-user transient (put the user ID in the identifier) with the current baby size post ID(s).